# How can I get the equivalent to a "this" keyword from d3 using d3.select()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 element which calls a function called `tick`.

```
      g.append("g")
     .attr("clip-path", 'url(' + $location.path() + '#clip)' )
     .append("path")
     .datum(data)
     .attr("class", "line")
     .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .on("start", tick);
```

Within the function tick, if I do `console.log(this)` I get something like the following printed to the console

```
<path class="line"></path>
```

However, if I do `console.log(d3.select("line"))` I get a huge object that I cannot manipulate the way I can using the `this` keyword.  What is the equivalent `d3` method to select an element and return the equivalent of the `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "equivalent" is:

```
console.log(d3.select("line").node())
```

Given this simple snippet:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="20" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>

var circle = d3.select("circle");
console.log(circle.node());
console.log(circle);
```

`console.log(circle.node())` gives you:

```
<circle cx="40" cy="40" r="20" fill="teal"></circle>
```

While `console.log(circle)` gives you:

```
zi {_groups: Array[1], _parents: Array[1]}
```

Note: I put quotes in "equivalent" because `this` depends on many things. So, that's the equivalent for your specific question.